# Filtering entire DataSet with many DataTables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataSet with many DataTables each containing many columns plus a column `buildingID`.
I would like to filter the entire DataSet by giving it a value for buildingID. I would like the rows in **every** table with a buildingID of, say 343.

Is there any quick possible way in C#?

Comment: linq is probably the best route, but to follow up with @NikhilAgrawal we need to know more about the filtering. What my gut is saying is you want to filter the tabels by building ID, this set of data represents a single building.  I would use linq to query the set, and then convert the set into an object representing the data tables.

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669073.aspx

Comment: gwin003 thanks for your response but that is filtering on a specific datatable in my dataset if i understand correctly. i would like to filter my entire dataset at once.

Comment: cgatian, your solution sound good. How do I go about that? I need to bo left with a fully functioning DataSet just all tables filtered by the buildingid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx), which returns filtered rows from a DataTable matching a criteria.

```
foreach (DataTable table in dataset.Tables) {
    var rows = table.Select("buildingID = " + buildingId.ToString());
    // Do stuff with filtered rows
}
```

To easily get all the rows that match your criteria, here's a LINQ expression:

```
var rows = dataset.Tables.SelectMany(
    t => t.Select("buildingID = " + buildingId.ToString()));
```

Comment: I need to have access to all the filtered tables at one time.

Comment: @Diane2: The LINQ query returns all filtered rows from all tables.

Comment: ah. I'm going to try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var ds1 = new DataSet();
foreach (DataTable dt in ds1.Tables)
{
    var filtereddt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("buildingID") == 1).ToList();

    //you can add these lists to another list array or something like that.
}
```